# Would NotificationListeners be removed, when RMIConnector has been closed?

Tags: java, rmi, jmx

We’re trying monitoring some important values via JMX. Currently, we scan all jvms every 10s, to update the value. But, the cost is too high(we have 1k+ jvm instances, the values doesn’t change very frequently). So, we try using NotificationListener.

The question is: if I add a listener on a mbean object, then, for some reason, I lost the connection/closed the connector. Will the listener be removed automatically from the mbean object?

If I connect to a remote MBeanServer, and add a listener, where is the listener instance created, the client-side? Or, the server-side?